# What are the alternatives to Chain of Responsibility design pattern?

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

I'm building the mail module for a line-of-business application. The situation is that when sending the mails in response to some input, they should be grouped so a user doesn't receive several consecutive mails with different items but just one with all items included. Also, mails should be grouped by a specific type, that depends on the type of input that created the mail notification, I have the list of inputs, and each one with its specific grouping type, for instance:

Hierarchy: **Employee** has **Processes** has **Requests** has **Activities**

**Activity 1:** *By Employee* (so a receiver will get all notifications of the processes he owns of this activity type in just one mail)

**Activity 2:** *By Process* (a receiver will get a group of all notifications of all requests on this process, and this activity type)

**Activity 3:** *By Request* (activities of this request will be grouped)

**Activity 4:** *By Activity* (each activity will be sent in a separate mail)

This groupings will change constantly.

You may think, well in order to do that inputs should be made at once so mails are generated at the same time and so grouped, otherwise how the system will know when to wait for other inputs and when to just send a separate mail?.. well the answer is both, so what I'm doing is setting a timer so the mail service runs every 5 minutes, some immediate mails might get delayed a few minutes, but that's an affordable trade off.

So I chose to use this [Chain of Responsability Design Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9194922/920359) and here's the structure:

[image: MailGroupingStructure]

So I have two interfaces **IGroupingType** which defines how each type should be, and has 2 methods: `CalculateGrouping()`: determines if this is the grouping of the activity. `GroupEmailsToSend()`: if this is the grouping, gets the mails list.

Interface **IGroupingHandler** is the service class that will call each grouping type, the `GetGroupingResult()` just calls the 2 methods on the **IGroupingType** concrete implemetations, first `CalculateGrouping()` to get the correct grouping, when it finds it, calls the `GroupEmailsToSend()`. This interface also registers the **next** node in the chain for each grouping.

The grouping Enum is just for returning the result of grouping calculations.

And then there's also the **EndOfChainSendingGrouping** class, in case no grouping was found I'll just send the mail right away.

Basicaly I just need some advice on this structure, since I'm kind of new to this pattern, does it have any pitfalls? is there something I can improve? or is there a better way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: I think [codereview.se] might be a better place for this...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think chaining sounds good and seems to be the best fitting here. Eventually the [Decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) pattern could be used for filtering the receiver lists.

Comment: Thanks a lot for stopping by, I'll surely take your advise into consideration.. ^_^

Comment: Another link on the decorator pattern to consider: https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/decorator